# asp.net set command argument

Tags: asp.net, commandargument

I am using OnRowDataBound to automatically add a link button to my grid view that looks like this. The problem I am having is setting the command argument.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID = "lnkDelete" Text = "Delete" CommandArgument = '<%# Eval("Value") %>' runat = "server" OnClick = "DeleteFile" />
```

Below is the code that adds the links. I set the command argument to Eval("Value") but that doesn't work. [Here is a link to the original code that I'm trying to change so it is dynamic.](http://aspsnippets.com/Blue/Articles/Display-list-of-files-from-Server-folder-in-ASPNet-GridView.aspx)

```
protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        LinkButton lnkView = new LinkButton();
        lnkView.ID = "lnkDelete";
        lnkView.Text = "Delete";
        lnkView.Click += DeleteFile;
        lnkView.CommandArgument = Eval("Value");
        e.Row.Cells[1].Controls.Add(lnkView);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RowDataBound` is not the right event to add controls dynamically because they need to be re-created on every consecutive postback. `RowDataBound` is triggered  only if you call `GridView.DataBind()`.

So use `RowCreated` instead, but assign the `CommandArgument` value in `RowDataBound` and don't use `Eval("Value")` but the actual datasource which you get from `e.Row.DataItem`.

Something like this should work:

```
protected void OnRowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        LinkButton lnkView = new LinkButton();
        lnkView.ID = "lnkDelete";
        lnkView.Text = "Delete";
        lnkView.Click += DeleteFile;
        e.Row.Cells[1].Controls.Add(lnkView);
    }
}

protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        LinkButton lnkView = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("lnkDelete");
        var rowView = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;
        lnkView.CommandArgument = rowView.Row.Field<string>("Value");
    }
}
```

If this throws an exception at runtime you need to change `(DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem` to the actual datasource which you can get from the debugger.

**Edit**: as commented it is a `ListItem` and you want to use it's `Value` property:

```
var item = (ListItem) e.Row.DataItem;
lnkView.CommandArgument = item.Value;
```

Comment: I am using DataBind. The links are being created it's just that they aren't working. I'm only a beginner and I still don't understand what I need to be doing from your example.

Comment: I think I understand it a bit better now. So with this part (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem; Does "DataRowView" need to be my datasource?

Comment: @Laserchalk: yes, it is the the single record in your datasource. It is a `DataRowView` if you use a `DataTable` as `DataSource`. If you use a different source you need to change the type. But what didn't you understand? Have you registered the event handler `OnRowCreated` and created the link there? What happened?

Comment: @Time Schmelter I don't think I need OnRowCreated because I am using DataBind. It turns out I needed to change DataRowView to the type ListItem. 

The line under that isn't working, it says  'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem' does not contain a definition for 'Row'. I'm guessing I need to use something different if I'm using a list item?

Comment: @Laserchalk: Normally you don't need to DataBind the grid on every postback. You only need it if you refresh the source (f.e. if you use `Paging` or `Sorting`). If it's a `ListItem` cast it accordíngly and use it's `Value` property. I've edited m answer.

Comment: thanks for the help it worked when I used OnRowCreated